# prove that if f is $C^1$ (meaning the derivative $f´$ is continuous) then it can be represented as the sum of an increasing and a decreasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

prove that if f is $C^1$ (meaning the derivative $f´$ is continuous) then it can be represented as the sum of an increasing and a decreasing function

I can´t find any solution for this problem Iwouold appreciate your help alot

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x) = \int_{a}^x f'(y) dy$. Now decompose $f'$ into its positive and negative parts.

Comment: why is it necessary to use the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: We can also see that $f'$ is bounded and hence $f$ is of bounded variation so that $f$ is expressible as a sum of increasing and decreasing function. But A Blumenthal's logic is much simpler and does not use concept of a function of bounded variation.

Comment: @ABlumenthal I got how you started and proceeding we get $f(x)=\overset{x}{\underset{a}{\int}}f_{(+)}'(y)dy-\overset{x}{\underset{a}{\int}}f_{(-)}'(y)dy$. How do we prove that each integral is increasing? Also, where do we need the continuity of $f'$?

Comment: I think I have it- let me know if there's an error: Let $g(x)=\overset{x}{\underset{a}{\int}}f_{+}'(t)dt$. Now, since $f'$ is continuous, we have $f_{(+)}'$ continuous which implies (by the Second Fundamental Theorem of calculus) that $g$ is differentiable and $g'(x)=f_{(+)}'(x)$. Because $g'(x)=f_{(+)}'(x)\ge0$, we can say that $g$ is an increasing function.